# Ember data: interpolated pluralization of model name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say I have a DS.Store model called "userPreferences". Say I have a backend API returning a SINGLE "userPreferences" record:

```
{"userPreferences":{"userID":"7","latitude":null,"longitude":null}}
```

Say I have a route that I want to use this model with:

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        myModel = this.store.find('userPreferences', 7);
        return myModel;
    }
});
```

If I try to do this, I get the following error from ember:

```
Error: No model was found for 'userPreference'
```

How do I specify that I'm already returning the singular form?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't ever plan to refer to a collection of userPreferences, as Steve H. suggested you might need to, you can define the phrase as uncountable:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.uncountable('userPreferences');
```

Just be careful, you might need to also define:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.uncountable('user_preferences');
```

Because at present the inflector doesn't assume that you want both defined. The underscore version is sometimes used by ember-data when referring to model properties during serialization. I always define both camelCase and underscore versions.

I've opened an issue about this on [ember-inflector](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector/issues/25).

Answer (score 0):

What do you plan to call a collection of `userPreferences`? Here, I'm calling them "manyUserPreferences", but I'd suggest something better :)  You can customize the way Ember understands the model names using an `Inflector`:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('userPreferences', 'manyUserPreferences');
```